# Do Arabs really speak with lengthened sounds?

Tags: quran, history, arabic, islamic-basis, tajweed

In Tajweed, especially in this [YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/@Arabic101), it is emphasized that some sounds should be lengthened up to 4 seconds.

I am not a linguist, and I am not a historian. Yet I know many languages in different levels (Persian, English, a little French, Quranic Arabic, Kurdi, Turkish), and in none of them, there is this concept of elongation of sounds.

And while I fear Allah and don't want to be a critic, it seems strange to me to think of Arabs contemporary to our Prophet (PBUH) who would speak with sounds that take 4 seconds to pronounce.

This makes me suspicious of the Tajweed rules altogether.

Can someone please explain where this comes from and how we can trust that it's true?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the *madd* is actually based on how the prophet would recite the Quran in his *tilawah*.

Answer (score 1):

Reciting the Quran is not an everyday conversation it is a ceremonial recital. Arabs might not elongate sounds that much in conversations but they do embellish words when reciting. In English conversations it is common to elongate sounds like saying Wowwwww, Noooooo, Realllllly.